# setTimeout does nothing (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i am creating a small discord bot. when setting up the commands that start after the client is on, one of them, which is setTimeout, does nothing.
here's a part of the code:

```
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('the bot is online!');
}); 

client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (message.content === 'ping') {
    message.reply({
        content: 'pong',
    })
}
   setTimeout(client.channels.cache.get('<channel ID>').send('time is out'), 3000);
});
```

no error shows, just nothing happening :( if you know what's wrong, please let me know

Comment: more of a syntax error if you ask me.. change your setTimeout line to `setTimeout(client.channels.cache.get('<channel ID>').send('time\'s out'), 3000);` since the `\\` prevents the string from escaping

Comment: the original message is written without the apostrophe, so it's not that. gonna change it real quick in a question, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you'll need to escape the ' character in your "time's out" string like so:

```
'time\'s out'
```

Second of all, you have to pass a callback to setTimeout as the first parameter so you need to use an arrow function like so.

```js
setTimeout(() => {client.channels.cache.get('<channel ID>').send('time\'s out')}, 3000);
```

Comment: I was incorrect about the second solution, it only works when the function (send) doesn't use the "this" keyword. In short, use the first solution.

Comment: first one worked! thank you so much <3

Comment: @eva No problem, if my solution helped you don't forget to mark as solved. Thanks.

Comment: jluims, please contact me on discord regarding "inifite-captcha" repository purchase, my username on discord is: langouts